# patch CBRP for ns2.35

Tags: routes, cluster-computing, ns2

Is there patch CBRP for ns2.35? If you can, send it to me and Explain the
 method of its patch step-to-step in ns2, and If a few patches are made in a ns2, how can it be patched?
 Thanks for help

Comment: AFAIK a stock ns-2.3(5) can do CBRP by default.

Comment: hello sir, What is AFAIK?

Comment: AFAIK means "As far as I know" https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=afaik

Comment: ns2.35 does not have the CBRP protocol